# C++ как правильно использовать template<typename T>?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пытаюсь сделать функцию, которая будет возвращать тип из шаблона, что-то вроде такого:

```
template<typename T>
T test_function<T>() {
///
}
```

Помещаю это и в .hpp и в .cpp. Компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> error: expected initializer before '<' token|
> ```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить.

Comment: `<T>` долой. И в .cpp эту функцию помещать не нужно, только в хедер.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
T test_function() {
///
}
```

Синтаксис `имя_шаблона<параметры/аргументы>` используется только при ссылке на уже ранее объявленный шаблон, а не при объявлении нового шаблона.

Comment: Если убрать `template<typename T>` из .cpp, как написали выше, то выходит ошибка "T does not name a type".

Comment: @Алексей Петродий: Так а зачем убирать? Не надо убирать. Зачем вы это делаете?

Comment: Не понял решения выше. Всё работает, благодарю.